# Drawing scrollable text on a CALayer

Tags: iphone, ios, scroll, calayer

I have the graphics context of a CALayer, and I would like to draw text inside of a "scrollview". I'm able to draw text just fine; however making it scrollable is harder.

I can't use UIScrollView for other reasons... is there anyway to draw scrollable text onto a calayer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there is no way to avoid using scroll view, because this is the main control class that supports scrolling. All other scroll-enabled controls inherit their scrollability from UIScrollView.